# Programmatically changing view on SegmentControl value changed

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I a have created two view in same ViewController in interface builder. One with tableview and other with few buttons. I want to change view on valueChanged event of segmentControl. How I can I call second view that I already have created .

***Please help.***

Comment: Add some code of what you already have!  In general though, your ViewController should already be the "owner" of you segmented control and your tableview at this point.  Sounds as if you should be able to directly access the data provider of the tableview, and then simply update the table for display!

Answer (score 0):

The handler of your segmented control:

```
-(void)controlDidChange:(id)sender {
   viewWithTable.hidden = !viewWithTable.hidden;
   viewWithButtons.hidden = !viewWithTable.hidden;
}
```